# Comparing two images using their RGB values. (Java)

Tags: java, image, filtering, rgb

I am trying to compare two images using their RGB values.

The code below is pulling the same RGB values for the unfiltered and filtered. I want the values to be different for the two images. (unfiltered and filtered are previously defined). The idea is that the greater the difference between the two images (before and after filtering) the poorer the filtered image is.

As my result I would expect two different sets of RGB values (1 for unfiltered and 1 for filtered). I get two sets of RGB values, however, both are identical.

I am creating a colour blind simulator and want to compare the value from both. Below is an example of a "Normal" vision image and a "Colour Blind" vision image.

[Unfiltered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZsyL.jpg) |
[Filtered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEFna.jpg)

```
filteredImage = unfilteredImage = Img;
```

...

```
ImageDisplay = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(filteredImage));
```

...

```
private void TypeButtonPressed()
{
    filteredImage(GetType());
}
```

...

```
int GetType()
{
    int type = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfTypes; i++)
    {
        JToggleButton TypeButton = TypeButtons[i];
        if (TypeButton.isSelected()) type = i;
    }

    TypeListener.SetType(type);
    return type;
}
```

...

```
        BufferedImage unfiltered = unfilteredImage;
        BufferedImage filtered = filteredImage;

        //unfilteredImage
        int ufwidth = unfiltered.getWidth();
        int ufheight = unfiltered.getHeight();

        Color unfilteredRGBValue = new Color(unfiltered.getRGB(ufwidth / 2, ufheight / 2));

        int ufred = unfilteredRGBValue.getRed();
        int ufgreen = unfilteredRGBValue.getGreen();
        int ufblue = unfilteredRGBValue.getBlue();

        System.out.println("Unfiltered Red: " + ufred);
        System.out.println("Unfiltered Green: " + ufgreen);
        System.out.println("Unfiltered Blue: " + ufblue);

        System.out.println("Unfiltered Score: " + ufred + ufgreen + ufblue);

        //filteredImage
        int fwidth = filtered.getWidth();
        int fheight = filtered.getHeight();

        Color filteredRGBValue = new Color(filtered.getRGB(fwidth / 2, fheight / 2));

        int fred = filteredRGBValue.getRed();
        int fgreen = filteredRGBValue.getGreen();
        int fblue = filteredRGBValue.getBlue();

        System.out.println("Filtered Red: " + fred);
        System.out.println("Filtered Green: " + fgreen);
        System.out.println("Filtered Blue: " + fblue);

        System.out.println("Filtered Score: " + fred + fgreen + fblue);
```

Thank you!

Ed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run the code I get the same RGB value for the filtered and unfiltered image. I was wondering if anyone could see why?

Comment: Edit your question above, specify what you expected to happen, and what is actually happening

Comment: we dont know wher those bufferedimages are coming from - do you know? maybe they are the same

Comment: I have updated the question - Thank you for the advice! :-)

Comment: you are just checking the center pixel and it could be the same why dont you try some other pixels - full code wher you actually read the two images might be helpful

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is just using the original images RGB values, I have used numerous images and exactly the same. I will try to show you how I loaded both in.

Comment: If any one is happy to review this code I am happy to send you over the full project.

Comment: I suggest sampling a random 25 pixels, calculate a mean, and see how much it diverges from the original. You need a mean to excluse white, grayscale and black pixels

Comment: as i said this looks suspicious filteredImage = unfilteredImage = Img; - for an image to be read properly I need to see     BufferedImage bim=null;
        try {
         bim=ImageIO.read(new File("c:/..../image.png"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("error in bim "); ex.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: What @gpasch said. Try some `System.out.println(filtered==unfiltered);`. If this prints `true`, then: There's your problem ;-)

Comment: It prints `true` :-( I have overcome this by every time you press a different type of filter it re-calculates the pixel value. This solves the issue. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here is taking a color of the one pixel that in the center of the image:

```
Color unfilteredRGBValue = new Color(unfiltered.getRGB(ufwidth / 2, ufheight / 2))
```

And if we look at javadoc for `getRGB()` method, it says

> There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method.

<strike>I think 8 bit is a pretty small precision since standard RGB image in jpeg format has 24 bits per pixel. Probably that middle pixels in your two images aren't so distinct.</strike>

EDIT: As Michael mentioned below, it's a precision of each color, so should be enogh.
Anyway comparing images by only one pixel is not a good idea, it's better to take some significant number of pixels and calculate mean or average of their differencies.

Comment: I thought you fixed it then! :-( but I'm pretty sure it is just using the original images RGB values, I have used numerous images and exactly the same. I wish it was possible to show all the code as this is quite a big project.

Comment: 8 bit << 8 bit << 8 bit = 24 bit... each color component. 8 bits gives room for 256 color combinations per component. so you get the r, 256, g, 256 and b, 256 positions. precision enough. but if your middle pixel is black... well...

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks suspicious with

```
 filteredImage = unfilteredImage = Img;
```

for an image to be read properly I need to see

```
BufferedImage bim1=null, bim2=null;
try {
  bim1=ImageIO.read(new File("c:/..../image1.png"));
  bim2=ImageIO.read(new File("c:/..../image2.png"));
}
catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```